Error while launching Optuna Dashboard in python
I am trying to launch optuna ( optuna-dashboard sqlite:///db.sqlite3 ) dashboard but I am receiving this error
optuna-dashboard : The term 'optuna-dashboard' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is c
orrect and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ optuna-dashboard sqlite:///db.sqlite3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (optuna-dashboard:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have installed also the optuna extension in VS, but it is experimental with less info than the localhost one.

I had the same error. Apparently optuna-dashboard is a package which must be installed on its own.
pip install optuna-dashboard

